# Conditional Generic return Rust

Tags: templates, generics, rust, traits

I'd like a struct method to return something that satisfies certain trait bounds when they're needed and when they are not needed something else.

My try (doesn't compile):

```
trait A<T> {                                                                                               
    type Item = T;                                                                                         
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Item;
}                                                                                                          

struct B {}

impl <T> A<T> for B where T: Send + Sync {
    type Item = T;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Item {
        // return
    }
}

impl <T> A<T> for B {
    type Item = T;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Item {
        // return
    }
}
```

In this case I want to return something which is Send + Sync when the outside context requires it and all other cases return what is defined in the second trait implementation.

It doesn't even have to be an implementation of a struct in my case, I simply thought it was necessary.

Is it possible to have the same function signature and have the compiler understand which of the two implementation is needed?

Comment: I think that what you want is [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844). This is currently *unstable*.

Comment: In the future, please make a minimal reproducible example. In general, it's impossible to implement you trait `A<T>` for any type `T`, no matter that `T: Send + Sync` or not.

Answer (score 0):

i have a quite an ugly solution for you:

```rust
trait A<T1, T2> {                                                                                               
    type Item1;
    type Item2;
    fn get1(&self) -> Self::Item1;
    fn get2(&self) -> Self::Item2;

}                                                                                                          

struct B {}

impl <T1, T2> A<T1, T2> for B 
where 
    T1: Send + Sync,
    T2: core::fmt::Debug + core::fmt::Display {
    type Item1 = ::std::sync::Arc<::std::string::String>;
    type Item2 = ::std::string::String;
    
    fn get1(&self) -> Self::Item1 {
        // return
        ::std::sync::Arc::new(String::from("asd"))
    }
    
    fn get2(&self) -> Self::Item2 {
        String::from("hello world")
    }
}
```

[`playground`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6aac165eb33f71583a2f3285b28449c6)

i know its not what you want, but if you dont have `many implementations` that you wanted for T (lets say 4), it does achieve what you want, i hope.

Comment: No it's sadly not what I want, I really need the same method to return different things according to the generic constraints of the context in which it is called.